# How to change from index to multiindex - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a data frame structured as below:

```
dict1 = {'id': {0: 11, 1: 12, 2: 13, 3: 14, 4: 15, 5: 16, 6: 19, 7: 18, 8: 17},
 'var1': {0: 20.272108843537413,
  1: 21.088435374149658,
  2: 20.68027210884354,
  3: 23.945578231292515,
  4: 22.857142857142854,
  5: 21.496598639455787,
  6: 39.18367346938776,
  7: 36.46258503401361,
  8: 34.965986394557824},
 'var2': {0: 27.731092436974773,
  1: 43.907563025210074,
  2: 55.67226890756303,
  3: 62.81512605042017,
  4: 71.63865546218487,
  5: 83.40336134453781,
  6: 43.48739495798319,
  7: 59.243697478991606,
  8: 67.22689075630252},
 'var3': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 2, 7: 2, 8: 2}}
ex = pd.DataFrame(dict1.to_dict()).set_index('id')
```

`id` is set as an index, but now I would like to create a MultiIndex from `var3` and `id`. But my following attempt fails:

```
ex.set_index(['var3', 'id'])
```

How can I then set a MultiIndex straight from Index? I know I can `reset_index` first and then set a MultiIndex, but it feels there has to be more elegant way.

Comment: long way - `ex.groupby('var3').apply(lambda x: x.assign())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFrame.set_index` has an `append` argument, which is `False` by default.

If you have a `DataFrame` already indexed by `"id"`, and you'd like to append `"var3"` to that, simply invoke:

```py
new_df = ex.set_index("var3", append=True)
```

As suggested by @piRSquared in the comments, you can also swap the order if you would like `"var3"` to come first by method chaining a call to `swaplevel`. I.e.:

```py
new_df = ex.set_index("var3", append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
```

Comment: `ex.set_index('var3', append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)`

Comment: @piRSquared Yeah, that would work, but in that case I'd say my solution is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
ex.set_index(['var3', ex.index])
```

Comment: For the record.  This might be more readable to some and it should be quicker.

Comment: @piRSquared heck, even `ex.reset_index().set_index(['var3', ex.index])` is more readable than your pro solution :)

Comment: I'd not say that is my recommendation.  I just wanted to show that `swaplevel` was necessary to make the answer accurate.  BTW, you could do this in place `df.index = [df.var3, df.index]`

Comment: @piRSquared hehe, just kidding. Yeah well not really as var3 would still exist in the frame.